# Why does this C++ vector use so much RAM?

Tags: c++, g++, ram

I have two files. One file is 15 gigabytes. The other is 684 megabytes. Both of these files have identical structures: they consist of many strings, one per line (which is to say, each string is separated by a `\n`).

While bored one day, and being the curious novice that I am, I decided to write a little C++ program to read these files into RAM. I compiled the program with G++ 8.1.1 on Fedora 28, and I found that when I read the small file into RAM, it consumes 2154 megabytes of RAM, and when I read the large file, it consumes 70.2 gigabytes of RAM. That's 3.15 times and 4.68 times the size of the original files, respectively.

Why is this the case?

This is the source code for this simple program. I'm using a std::vector to store each line as an std::string. I get the feeling that this question may actually boil down to, how does C++ handle strings? Is there an alternative datatype I should consider using?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::vector<std::string> inStrings;
    std::string line;
    inStrings.reserve(1212356398);
    inFile.open("bigfile.txt");
    if (!inFile)
    {
            std::cerr << "Unable to open the hardcoded file" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
    }
    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {
            inStrings.push_back(line);
    }
    std::cout << "done reading" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are reserving space for more than 1GB of string objects.  Assume that each string object has 16 bytes of overhead (which might be low even on a 32-bit system - I haven't checked in a while) regardless of the string contents then you have taken up 16GB before you even read anything from the file.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects when you create them. That is, change `std::ifstream inFile; ... inFile.open("crackstation.txt");` to `std::ifstream inFile("crackstation.txt");`. And note that `if (!inFile)` isn't strictly necessary; the subsequent IO operations will fail gracefully if the file isn't working.

Comment: How did you determine how much memory the program ended up using? Your program doesn't examine memory; if you're looking at the OS's readout of how much memory the **program** has used, that's not a valid measure of how much memory the vector and the strings are actually using. This program thrashes memory, allocating and freeing many memory blocks. There's  a great deal of unused memory in the value that the OS gives you.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, I can accept that each string has some overhead, but why would that overhead be three times greater than the quantity of data being read in?

@PeteBecker Yes, I used htop to determine how much memory the program used. When the `cin.get()` statement waited for input, and before memory was freed, I checked htop. The OS sure seemed convinced it couldn't give any other applications that memory.

Answer (score 5):

If you have tried implementing a dynamic array in school or as an exercise, recall allocation strategies like doubling the capacity each time the capacity is full; similarly the vector prepares to store more than it actually stores.

Meanwhile, a string by itself stores a length, a capacity as well, and <s>a reference counter</s>, which makes 3 words at minimum even for an empty string.

**Edit**

Yeah, I guess the bit about the reference counter wasn't correct. I was remembering it was 3 words, and for some reason thought it wasn't counting the pointer to the actual allocated memory. But I guess maybe it is just that: the pointer to the actual string.

In any case the actual story differs due to optimizations across compilers. Search "std::string memory allocation" or something like that to read more.

Comment: Also, there is short string optimization which allocates a minimum chunk for smaller strings. Normally this provides significantly improved performance at the cost of more memory. It can add up.

Comment: A reference counter? I'd be surprised to see this in a (modern) implementation of `std::string`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin do you not need that to implement string views?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Nope, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view): "It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that std::string_view does not outlive the pointed-to character array."

Comment: Reference counting in `string_view` would also make their use awkward/broken when dealing with static string literals and heap allocated character arrays.

Comment: C++11 formally outlawed copy-on-write `std::string`

Comment: I'm surprised libc++ and libstdc++ both go for actually doubling the capacity. [MSVC](http://rextester.com/VFXSJ93894) goes for what I'd thought to be the typical 1.5x

Comment: Surely a length and a capacity are relatively small compared to the size of a string, though. Two are some kind of number, may it be an unsigned int or something else, and one is a sequence of bytes. Right? Is my understanding flawed? Either way, I may have misunderstood something, because I still don't see why the overhead is three times the size of the data.